# Smb helped smb reached smth

Tags: grammar

In the following phrase, is it a correct usage of the word "reached"?

"People just like you helped Companyname *reached* countries around the world".

I would use the verb "to reach" in the infinitive form:

"People just like you helped Companyname *to reach* countries around the world".

Comment: *People… helped Companyname in reaching countries around the world*  or *People… helped Companyname reach countries around the world*, perhaps. See *[Help + Noun + Gerund or Infinitive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90175)* and *[What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb “help”: with or without “to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578)* for some background. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest.

Comment: Please [edit] this to stop using the terrible abbreviations of "smb" and "smth".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "reached" here is incorrect.  You are correct to use the infinitive form, "to reach", as that is the proper form in relation to "help", i.e. "help to".

Much of the time the "to" is omitted, making "help to reach" into "help reach":

*"People just like you helped Companyname reach countries around the world".*

You may find this question and answer helpful: [What is the correct way to use infinitive after the verb "help": with or without "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without)